# How to use correctly Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

why won't combining them this work

```
df = pd.DataFrame(metar_clouds_array[0],metar_clouds_array[1])
print(df) 

 metar_clouds_array =[[['OVC'], ['OVC'], ['OVC'], ['OVC'], ['OVC'], ['BKN', 'OVC'], ['BKN', 'OVC'], ['BKN', 'OVC'], ['BKN', 'OVC'], ['BKN', 'OVC'],['BKN', 'OVC'], ['OVC'], ['OVC'], ['OVC'], ['OVC'], ['-9999'], ['-9999'], ['-9999'], ['-9999'], ['-9999'], ['-9999'], ['-9999'], ['OVC'], ['BKN', 'BKN'], ['BKN', 'OVC'], ['FEW', 'BKN'], ['FEW', 'BKN'], ['FEW'], ['FEW', 'FEW'], ['FEW', 'SCT'], ['FEW', 'SCT'], ['FEW', 'SCT'], ['FEW', 'FEW', 'SCT'], ['FEW', 'FEW', 'SCT'], ['FEW', 'SCT']], [['014'], ['010'], ['008'], ['006'], ['005'], ['005', '012'], ['006', '012'], ['007', '014'], ['007', '014'], ['006', '012'], ['006', '012'], ['006'], ['004'], ['003'], ['002'], ['-9999'], ['-9999'], ['-9999'], ['-9999'], ['-9999'], ['-9999'], ['-9999'], ['002'], ['003', '020'], ['003', '017'], ['003', '021'], ['003', '020'], ['025'], ['020', '150'], ['025', '250'], ['033', '250'], ['033', '250'], ['030', '150', '250'],['030', '150', '250'], ['150', '250']]]
```

But this will

```
dz = pd.DataFrame(metar_clouds_array[1])
print(dz)

dm = pd.DataFrame(metar_clouds_array[0])
print(dm)
```

it out puts

```
        0     1     2
0     014  None  None
1     010  None  None
2     008  None  None
3     006  None  None
4     005  None  None
5     005   012  None
6     006   012  None
7     007   014  None
8     007   014  None
9     006   012  None
10    006   012  None
11    006  None  None
12    004  None  None
13    003  None  None
14    002  None  None
15  -9999  None  None
16  -9999  None  None
17  -9999  None  None
18  -9999  None  None
19  -9999  None  None
20  -9999  None  None
    .
    .
    .

    0     1     2
0     OVC  None  None
1     OVC  None  None
2     OVC  None  None
3     OVC  None  None
4     OVC  None  None
5     BKN   OVC  None
6     BKN   OVC  None
7     BKN   OVC  None
8     BKN   OVC  None
9     BKN   OVC  None
10    BKN   OVC  None
11    OVC  None  None
12    OVC  None  None
13    OVC  None  None
14    OVC  None  None
15  -9999  None  None
16  -9999  None  None
17  -9999  None  None
18  -9999  None  None
19  -9999  None  None
20  -9999  None  None
```

Could I just add the DataFrames together some how ?

I am wondering why the DataFrame then put None because it should be able to do it. These are cloud height and cloud types from surface observation which I'm going to store in a csv and txt file for comparison later.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I figured it out.

result = pd.concat([df, dm], axis=1, sort=False)